# Raycast returns miss even though it clearly hits its target collider, how to debug?

Tags: unity, raycasting

I'm trying to debug the following situation:

[image]

The raycast returns miss even though it clearly hits its target collider.

The target is a stock 3D Object Unity Cube.
The script firing the rays has a `Public GameObject` called 'target', the cube is correctly set as the target.

Here is the bulk of the raycasting I am doing. The rays are aimed at an array of positions within the bounds of the box called 'vertices'.

This was working yesterday and I didn't change the code and now it no longer works and I am completely stumped with no idea how to even begin to debug why.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
    {
        Vector3 direction = vertices[i] - self.position;

        Ray ray = new Ray(self.position, direction);

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out raycastHit))
        {
            if (raycastHit.collider.transform == target)
            {
                Debug.DrawRay(self.position, direction, Color.green, 5.0f, true);
                hitCount += 1f;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.DrawRay(self.position, direction, Color.red, 5.0f, true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us how you populate your vertices array?

Comment: When you say "no longer works" what exactly does it do? Does it output nothing? Does it give the wrong output?

Comment: Also, in your screenshot, I can't help but notice that we see the green outline of a box collider *behind* your cube, but no collider outline around your cube itself. Is that just a coincidence, or have you modified the collider's position relative to the display mesh? (If the screenshot weren't cropped so tight and we could see the inspector, we might not need to ask that)

Comment: The green box is something else entirely, you can ignore it.
It no longer works as in all rays return no hit.
The vertex array is a matrix and its like a full page of code long.

The bug was in if (raycastHit.collider.transform == target). Target is a collider but it was comparing transform to collider for some reason.

Comment: @Bunp It was comparing Transform to Collider because that's how your code is written. `raycastHit.collider.transform == target`. If you don't want to use the transform, change it to `raycastHit.collider == target`.

Answer (score 1):

> I am completely stumped with no idea how to even begin to debug why.

Always start with some basic debug logging:

```
if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out raycastHit))
{
    Debug.Log("Hit collider: " + hit.collider +", target: " + target);
    Debug.Log("hit.collider == target" + hit.collider == target);
```

> The script firing the rays has a Public GameObject called 'target'

Your code says `if (raycastHit.collider.transform == target)`. If `target` is a GameObject, the result will always be false, because the Transform component is a Component, not a GameObject.

> Target is a collider but it was comparing transform to collider for some reason.

Wait, is `target` a collider or a GameObject? If it's a collider, why are you comparing it to the Transform of the object that the Raycast hit? Collider and Transform are different components and will never be equal.

This will probably do what you want:

`if (raycastHit.collider.transform == target.transform)`